# Scala: Avoid mutable instance variables

Tags: scala, playframework, server-sent-events

I am trying to avoid mutable instance variables in class but I am not able to figure out how in the following case while trying to create a User in my Play application:

The user information like the membershipList can change while the user is logged in. When such a thing changes, the application notifies the user using Play's `Ok.feed(...)` as Server Sent Event (SSE).

**EDIT**: @drstevens pointed out that the Unicast feed must be moved out as `User` was shown as Case class. Editing to make `User`not a case class.

```
class User(id: Long, firstName: String, lastName: String, 
           membershipList: List[Group], @volatile private var signedIn = true) {
  private var infoSentOnce = false;
  private val unicastFeed: Option[Enumerator[JsValue]] = if(signedIn) Concurrent.unicast[JsValue](onStart, onComplete, onError) else None

  private def onStart(channel: Channel[JsValue]) {
    if(signedIn) {
      if(!infoSentOnce) {
        channel.push(json)
        channel.end
        infoSentOnce = true;
      }
    } else {
      channel.eofAndEnd
    }          
  }

  private def onComplete = ....

  private def onError(message: String, iteratee: Iteratee[JsValue]) = .....

  def json = {
    .....
  }

  def signedOut = signedIn = false

  def feed = unicastFeed
}
```

Action in the controller will be:

```
class MyController extends Controller with MyAuth {
  def userFeed = Authenticated { request =>   
     request.user.feed.fold(Ok(request.user.json)) { feed =>
       Ok.feed(feed 
               >& Concurrent.buffer(10)
               >& new EventSource()).as("text/event-stream"))
     }
  }
}
```

`signedIn` & `infoSentOnce` are the two mutable variables that I would like to change it to be immutable. `infoSentOnce` being mutable may also relate to me not understanding Play's enumerator properly. Whenever the user information changes, I create a new User object but I copy over the Unicast enumerator from the previous instance of the same user. Json is to be pushed once into the user's Unicast channel when a new User instance gets created.

Maybe having `infoSentOnce` as var is okay here as it cannot be modified by any outside interactions?

Comment: Do you have a complete example of what you are trying to do? How will the Enumerator be used? When will it be used? I would still try to separate the `Enumerator` part from a the `User`.

Comment: @drstevens Updated the question with more details.

Comment: If you want to do a one time immutable initialization then `lazy val` will do the trick. It can be assigned only once.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `User` class is handling events itself, it is going to have to maintain state, and that means being mutable.

Immutable classes are most useful when things are done *to* them by outside forces, like if `MyController` is signing in the user, and can make a `user = user.copy(signedOn = true)`.
If the class itself is managing the state, well, then, you need mutability.

You can sort of cheat here to get all `val`s by replacing your boolean variables with `AtomicBoolean`s, but that just moves the mutability one level away.